# Why did my terminal prompt change?

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm in Webstorm, terminal.  All of a sudden my prompt changes.  Now I see ultra-jess:[rest of path] whereas before I was seeing something different.  Why would this change?

[image]

Comment: Webstorm will use your regular terminal settings. If you do the same thing from Terminal.app does it do the same thing? You probably have a setting or she'll extension to change the prompt in certain directories.

Comment: What did you see before? What do you want to see?